# import play framework module as jar into java project

Tags: jar, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have created a play module, how I can import the exported jar to normal java project(not play project)?

When I tried it it gives error:

> The type play.libs.F$Promise cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from  required .class files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the play libs as well. Have a look at the [deployment documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.0/ProductionDist). `activator dist` allows you to create a standalone distribution for your entire play-app.

You can also search the jars in the output for the one which contains the classes you need and just add this one jar to your project.

Or: use sbt/maven to manage your dependencies and add the entire play-framework. (seems to be a bit of an overkill though)

Comment: so I should do activator dist then get all libs inside the folder libs and put it in dependencies.

Comment: Try just to include those you really need, so you don't clutter up your app with unnecessary libraries.